# React Component from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, iframe, jinja2

I am trying to create a React Component that will render a response from AJAX call.
My use case is this -
I have a Jinja Flask BE that sits behind AWS API GW and needs custom headers and the `Authorization` header in order to return the HTML and JS files.
I want to show the content coming back inside an IFrame or other sort of React Component but I understood I can't send Request Headers in an IFrame.

Is there anyway that I can show the content from the API GW inside a React app? and send the headers in order to get it correctly?

If I am using Chrome and sending the headers on force I see that it works and the site is presented

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use Axios package like this.

```
axios.get('url', {headers: "Authorization":'foobar'})
```

and if you have more than one API calls then create separate axios instance like this:

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://domain.api/api',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'Authorization': 'foobar'}
});

instace.get('/v2')
```

For more information:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: Hey, thanks ! but I want to show the response from the Axios in my react app, how can I do that? The call itself wasn't the problem, the problem is how to present the content I got from it.

Comment: Depend on your target url, if your target is using Content Security Policy (CSP), you can't.